# Hide nested button based on an inputs value

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a button inside it which I need to hide.

```
  <form method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7245">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="removesubmissionconfirm">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" title="">Remove submission</button>
  </form>
```

There are multiple forms with the exact same values as the above, the only difference being the value="removesubmissionconfirm". Is it possible to hide the button based on that value using only css?

I've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, but it may be in this specific example, considering the fact that the button comes directly after the hidden action field. Try this:

```
input[value="removesubmissionconfirm"] + button {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. I did not know about the + selector.

Comment: Yea, it's an old one, but a bit obscure, doesn't have too much uses imho. But in this particular case it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the [+ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) :

```css
input[value="removesubmissionconfirm"] + button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7245">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="removesubmissionconfirm">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" title="">Remove submission</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. I did not know about the + selector.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[value="removesubmissionconfirm"] + button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <form method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7245">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="removesubmissionconfirm">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" title="">Remove submission</button>
  </form>
```